# Как установить модуль open_sll для php на CentOs?

Tags: php, linux, centos, openssl

Для отправки почты хочу использовать smtp через ssl. Выдает ошибку:

```
Unable to find the socket transport "SSL" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

Лезу в php.ini - там нет строк, нужных мне. Добавляю строчку extension=php_openssl.so - но все ровно пустота ведь в /usr/lib/php/modules у меня файлика php_openssl.so нету. Где его взять не знаю, как установить его - тоже не знаю.

Пробую установить  через **yum install php-openssl** - пишет

```
 *Package matching php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.i686 already installed. Checking for update.  Nothing to do*
```

Вот список установленных пакетов:

```
php-bcmath-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-pdo-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-symfony-class-loader-2.7.9-2.el6.remi.noarch
php-mysql-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-pear-Net-Socket-1.0.14-1.el6.remi.noarch
php-pear-Net-Sieve-1.3.4-4.el6.remi.noarch
php-imap-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-soap-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-mbstring-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-process-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-php-gettext-1.0.11-12.el6.remi.noarch
php-symfony-common-2.7.9-2.el6.remi.noarch
php-cli-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-gd-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-intl-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-pspell-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-xml-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-pear-Auth-SASL-1.0.6-1.el6.remi.noarch
php-pear-Net-LDAP2-2.2.0-1.el6.remi.noarch
php-pear-Net-SMTP-1.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
php-pear-Net-IDNA2-0.1.1-6.el6.remi.noarch
php-phpseclib-2.0.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
php-tidy-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts-6.2.12-1.el6.remi.noarch
php-recode-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
vesta-php-0.9.8-15.i686
phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.2-1.el6.remi.noarch
php-mcrypt-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-xmlrpc-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-common-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-ldap-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686
php-pear-1.10.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
php-kolab-net-ldap3-1.0.3-1.el6.remi.noarch
php-pear-Mail-Mime-1.10.0-1.el6.remi.noarch
php-tcpdf-6.2.12-1.el6.remi.noarch
```

Еще немного информации:

PHP 5.4.45 (cli), 
php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.i686

Вот php_info(); вывод, часть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А установлен ли собственно сам openssl?

Comment: Package openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6_7.2.i686 already installed and latest version.
Вестимо, все установлено...

Comment: Пакет openssl-libs тоже установлен?

Comment: @newman такого пакета даже не находит нигде). Не уверен, что понял как его установить. yum install openssl-libs пишет, что пакет такой не найден

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увы, но почему-то скрипт из интернета, которым я тестил смтп - выдавал такую ошибку. Замена скрипта помогла.

И да, файлика с расширением *.so  там и не должно было лежать в папке вышеозвученной. Так как этот модуль входит в другие пакеты